# Solving reduce/reduce and shift/reduce conflicts in bison grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I am trying to solve the r/r and s/r conflicts in the following bison grammar

```
%right TOK_IF TOK_ELSE
%right '='
%left  TOK_EQ TOK_NE '<' TOK_LE '>' TOK_GE
%left  '+' '-'
%left  '*' '/' '%'
%right TOK_POS TOK_NEG '!' TOK_NEW
%left  TOK_BLK '.' TOK_CALL
%precedence  TOK_PARENT

%start start

        expr       : expr BINOP expr   {$$=$2->adopt($1,$2);}
                   | UNOP              {$$ = $1;}
                   | allocator         {$$ = $1;}
                   | call              {$$ = $1;}
                   | expr '[' expr ']' %prec TOK_BLK  {
                     destroy($4);
                     $$ = $2->adopt($1,$3);}
                   | '(' expr ')' %prec TOK_PARENT {$$ = $2;}
                   | expr '.' expr {$$ = $2->adopt($1,$3);}
                   | variable {$$= $1;}
                   | constant {$$ = $1;}
                   ;
        BINOP      : TOK_IF   {$$ = $1;}
                   | TOK_ELSE {$$ = $1;}
                   | '='      {$$ = $1;}
                   | TOK_EQ   {$$ = $1;}
                   | TOK_NE   {$$ = $1;}
                   | '<'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | TOK_LE   {$$ = $1;}
                   | '>'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | TOK_GE   {$$ = $1;}
                   | '+'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | '-'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | '*'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | '/'      {$$ = $1;}
                   | '%'      {$$ = $1;}
                   ;

        UNOP       : '+' expr %prec TOK_POS {
                   $1->swap_token_code(TOK_POS);
                   $$ = $1->adopt($2);
                   }
                   | '-' expr %prec TOK_NEG{
                   $1->swap_token_code(TOK_NEG);
                   $$ = $1->adopt($2);
                   }
                   | '!' expr {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
                   ;
        allocator  : TOK_NEW TOK_IDENT '('')' {
                   destroy($3);
                   $2->swap_token_code(TOK_TYPEID);
                   $$ = $1->adopt($2);
                   }
                   | TOK_NEW TOK_STRING '(' expr ')'{

                   }
                   | TOK_NEW basetype '[' expr ']'{
                   destroy($3);destroy($5);
                   $1->swap_token_code(TOK_NEWARRAY);
                   $$ = $1->adopt($2,$4);
                   }
                   ;
        call       : TOK_IDENT '(' exprs ')' %prec TOK_CALL{
                    destroy($4);
                    $2->swap_token_code(TOK_CALL);
                    $$ = ($2->adopt($1))->cannibalize($3);
                   }
                   ;
        exprs      : exprs expr  {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
                   | {$$ = new astree ('{',{0,0,0}, "}");}
                   ;

        variable   : TOK_IDENT  {$$ = $1;}
               | expr '[' expr ']'{
               destroy($4);
               $$ = $2->adopt($1,$3);
               }
               | expr '.' TOK_IDENT {$$ = $2->adopt($1,$3);}
               ;
        constant   :TOK_INTCON    {$$ = $1;}
                |TOK_CHARCON   {$$ = $1;}
               |TOK_STRINGCON {$$ = $1;}
               |TOK_NULL      {$$ = $1;}
               ;
    %%
```

I think the problem is the rule expr : expr BINOP expr because when I get rid of it, it stops showing these conflicts. I have declared the precedence rules above to avoid shift/reduce conflicts, but it looks like it's not working. Can someone give me shortcuts in debugging an ambiguous grammar?. Disregard the semantic rules.

```
parser.y: warning: 24 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
parser.y: warning: 56 reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-rr]
parser.y:140.14-143.12: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
           | expr '[' expr ']'{
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
parser.y:144.14-56: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
            | expr '.' TOK_IDENT {$$ = $2->adopt($1,$3);}
```

UPDATE: I detected a problem in my understanding

Although I am getting the right results, my compiler keeps telling that there is  a shift/reduce conflict in the following grammar. I think there shouldn't be conflicts because I specified precedence and associativity  properly.

```
%left '+'
%left '*'

%%
expr : expr BINOP expr
     | TOK_INTCON 

BINOP :  '+'  
      |  '*'
%%
```

Comment: Not an answer, but several of your code actions are incorrect. There is no reason to DESTROY a `]`, or to provide the binary operator as an argument to `adopt()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. An answer on my latter problem would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response is to your UPDATE section, since that's kind of the heart of the problem.

The TL;DR answer is that the precedence-and-associativity declarations `%left '+'` and `%left '*'` apply while parsing `BINOP` but not while parsing `expr`, so they're too early (they do nothing at this point) and are gone by the time they are needed.

---

I modified your example so that Bison can handle it:

```
$ cat expr.y
%token TOK_INTCON
%left '+'
%left '*'

%%
expr : expr BINOP expr
     | TOK_INTCON 

BINOP :  '+'  
      |  '*'
%%
$ bison -v expr.y
expr.y: warning: 2 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
```

The point of `-v` here is to write `expr.output` which shows how Bison is interpreting your grammar.  You can peruse this to see exactly where the shift/reduce conflict occurs—but in short, it occurs when the input contains, e.g.,

```
1 op 2 op 3
```

The grammar allows this to be parsed as:

```
  op
 /  \
1    op
    /  \
   2    3
```

(which is the parse tree you get if you choose "shift" instead of "reduce" each time), or:

```
    op
   /  \
  op    3
 /  \
1    2
```

What `%left`, `%right`, and `%nonassoc` do is assign a precedence to a *specific token*.  Now, as noted in [the Bison documentation section on how precedence works](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_8.html#SEC75), precedence *does* flow through to rules, but crucially, *not to nonterminals themselves*: they only apply to individual rules within a nonterminal.  They function to decide whether to shift to a new state, or reduce by a rule, and once the shift or reduce has happened, the decision is already made.  [(This is natural since the token or nonterminal is *recognized by* the shifting or reduction, which gives you either a new node for your parse tree, or a partial parse tree.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser)

By reducing all your binary operators to a `binop` nonterminal, you rob the parser of a way to distinguish between each different binary operator.  In the LALR grammar that Bison will generate, if you have a separate rule for each operator, you get a separate state for each one, which allows a separate shift-or-reduce decision.

```
$ cat expr-repaired.y
%token TOK_INTCON
%left '+'
%left '*'

%%
expr : expr '+' expr
     | expr '*' expr
     | TOK_INTCON 
%%
$ bison -v expr-repaired.y
$
```

Interestingly, the total number of states remains the same (both `expr.output` and `expr-repaired.output` show seven states).  However, the *meaning* of the states is different.  Several states for handling the old `BINOP` nonterminal are gone; in their place are multiple states for correctly handling the left-associative, different-precedence operators while deciding whether to reduce `expr <some-op> expr` depending on how we decided to reduce the *first* `expr`.  Look closely at the new state 6, for instance:

```
State 6

    1 expr: expr . '+' expr
    1     | expr '+' expr .
    2     | expr . '*' expr

    '*'  shift, and go to state 5

    $default  reduce using rule 1 (expr)
```

If we are in this state and the next token is `*`, we shift, so that we'll handle `expr * expr` and reduce it before we reduce `expr + (expr-from-reduction)`.

Comment: Ok, so what I understood is that bison can recognize the precedence of '"*" and "+" but not the one of BINOP

Comment: That's not quite right: the problem is that `BINOP` doesn't *have* precedence. You could, in effect, give it one, by using `%prec` inside a rule ... but that's just *one*, not two *different* ones depending on which operator it had matched.

Comment: I got it thank you. I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254910/solving-the-following-shift-reduce-conflict-in-bison-grammar